# implement serviceThrottling options in silverlight application

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am a beginner in Silverlight. I have developed a Silverlight chat application. In a single Silverlight window open more than one chat windows every chat window create a connection with wcf service but when it reaches 10 then the application is stop working and break all communications from **wcf polling duplex service**. I already have configured my wcf service web config file with :

```
<serviceThrottling 
    maxConcurrentCalls="10000" 
    maxConcurrentSessions="10000" 
    maxConcurrentInstances="10000" />
```

***but it has no effect***. Do I need to set these settings in silverlight application also? Please hep me. How is it possible to load thousands of chat windows on a one client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The web browser will only allow so many connections to a web server.  There are reg hacks/settings hacks for browsers to modify how many connections.  I would rethink your chat window gets it's data from the WCF service.  For instance, maybe you send all chatroom data down one wcf client, and have your application send them to their constituents UI.